# Can not send data to server with post request

Tags: php, post, curl, request, server

i have 2 file.

**file one.php**:

```
<?php 
    include 'config/dbconnect.php';
    $query = mysql_query("select * from getgift_logs where status = 1") or die(mysql_error());
    echo("<table border='1'>");
    echo("<tr>");
        echo("<td>User ID</td>");
        echo("<td>Yes</td>");
    echo("</tr>");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo("<tr>");
        echo("<td>".$row['user_id']."</td>");
        echo "<td><button class='yes' gift_id = '".$row['id']."'>Yes</button></td>";
        echo("</tr>");
    }
    echo("</table>");
 ?>
 <div id='result'></div>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $('.yes').click(function() {
        var trans_id=$(this).attr("gift_id");   
    $.ajax({
    url : "process.php?id="+trans_id,
    type: "GET",  
    success:   function(result) {
         $('#result').html(result);
         },  
        });
       });
    </script>
```

File **one.php** i send one get request to **process.php** file. And this is file **process.php**:

```
<?php 
    include("config/dbconnect.php");
    date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
    $id = $_POST['trans_id'];

    $query = mysql_query("select * from getgift_logs where id = '".$id."'");

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $topuplink = $row['topuplink'];
        $trans_id = $row['trans_id'];
        $clientsecret = $row['clientsecret'];
        $accesstoken = $row['accesstoken'];
        $lost_money = $row['lost_money'];
        $status = $row['description'];
        $time = date('Ymdhis',time());
        $sign = md5($money."|".$trans_id."|".$time."|".$clientsecret);
         $ch = curl_init();
                $data = array(
            'topup_money' => $lost_money,
            'reference_trans_id' => $trans_id,
            'description'=>$status,
            'request_time'=> $time,
            'sign'=>$sign
            );

              $postvars = '';
              foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
                $postvars .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
              }
              $url = $topuplink."".$accesstoken;
              curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
              curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
              curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
              curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
              $response = curl_exec($ch);
              print_r($response);
              curl_close ($ch); 
?>
```

In **process.php** file i send *POST REQUEST* but it not work(It not send data to server).

I don't know i wrong something? Please, help me! Thank all!

Comment: Your sending a `GET`, not a `POST` or am I misreading? `type: "GET"`..

Comment: I sending a  GET to process.php. And in process.php i sending POST  to server.

Comment: You need `$id=$_GET['id']` instead of `$id = $_POST['trans_id'];` as you are passing `url : "process.php?id="+trans_id,` in ajax

Comment: yes, i have fix it. But it not proplem. Proplem is i can't send post request to server in curl :((

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: it not show error. But response: data:null

Comment: Please check your curl_exec() response via store in variable and print with exit. Like print_r($response); exit;

Comment: `print_r($response)` return `{""data":null""}`

Comment: Ok, did you check *$row* having proper value?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd yes, when i `echo` it having value

Comment: @mrdragon: Means *$postvars* and *$url* also contain desire values, right?

Comment: And also try `var_dump(curl_error($ch));` in conjunction with `curl_errno`

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd i tried `var_dump(curl_error($ch))`. Response:`bool(false)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98957/discussion-between-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd-and-mrdragon).

Comment: Do not use `mysql_query`, it is now deprecated instead use `mysqli_query`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$postvars = '';
foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
    $postvars .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
}
rtrim($postvars , '&'); // remove last &

$url = $topuplink."".$accesstoken;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data)); // count of total post fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: can you tell me what is displaying in response?

Comment: `print_r($response)` return `{""data":null""}`

Comment: Method is correct though, please check URL and file what it's returning to you.